# The hyperlink option is grayed out in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

The `Insert > Hyperlink` option used to work fine before, but now it is grayed out.

I tried the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> keyboard shortcut, but it doesn't work either. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

**P.S.** It is a work machine and I have almost no admin privileges. My Windows version is 1803, and Office version 14.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be because the `Format Text` option is `Plain Text`, which doesn't support hyperlinks. You can check this from the ribbon bar

[image]

Change the format to HTML, and normal service should resume.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.